# Why is almost all of the 3 GB RAM on my HP G62 laptop always used?

Tags: ram, memory-usage, info, free

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 on a computer with 3072 MB RAM and 20 GB swap. It is an HP G62 laptop which overheats pretty regularly.

When I type `free -mt` in the terminal the output is:

```
free -mt
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2873       2741        132          0          9       1084
-/+ buffers/cache:       1648       1225
Swap:        19529         42      19487
Total:       22403       2784      19619
```

Note the free memory: 132 MB!! The maximum free memory I have observed is 750 MB directly after startup. Whats happening???

also note the temperatures:

```
sensors

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +78.0°C  (crit = +99.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +75.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 2:       +72.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
```

Comment: IMO, there really is not enough information in your question to connect your CPU temps to your RAM. It could be a "run away" process. It could also be that your laptop ventilation is clogged. Have you tried powering off, removing the battery, and then blowing out the dust with a compressed gas duster?

Comment: It isn't, you are just looking at the wrong line.  You have 1.2 gb free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is "simply" not as bad as you think. Linux uses some of your ram for disk caching.  Take a look at the explanations and suggestions on this page: [*Linux ate my RAM!*](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/).

```
Mem:          2873       2741        132          0          9       1084

-/+ buffers/cache:       1648       1225
```

this tells you that you've got `1225 MB` free...

i don't know what's the "normal" temp of your system, but i don't think it's heavily addicted to your ram usage...

Comment: but isn't 1,2 gb of RAM still very low for a 3gb RAM computer?

Comment: not unless you plan on copying gigabytes of files or playing any large games... Besides, if the RAM is full, the swap will take the overflow - your swap size is plentiful for that, you could even reduce it to ~6GB and it probably would be fine...

Comment: hmmm, i suggest you to use top (or htop that is nicer) to see what application needs your ram. for example, if you running a mysql-server it can take a lot of your ram just by starting...

my ubuntu 13.1 with xfce takes about 800mb, firefox uses 300 of this and thunderbird about 150mb..., music playback ... and so on...

Comment: funny someone actually bought/hired a .com domain name for that. Thanks for the quick help!